# Function/subsquery table with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, subquery, plpgsql

Using PostgresSQL 9.3, OSX.

I have hacked together the function below.
Shockingly, it works and returns a single column table of zip codes based on location.

I now want to for/loop through those results running a select query for each of those zip codes returning a single multiple column table. What would be the best way to incorporate the following SELECT query into this function?

```
SELECT "NPI" FROM doc
WHERE "Provider Business Mailing Address Postal Code"='<ZIPCODERESULTS FROM BELOW>'; 

CREATE FUNCTION get_npizips (text) RETURNS TABLE(a char(5)) AS '
  DECLARE
    -- Declare aliases for user input.
    npi_id ALIAS FOR $1;
    -- Declare a variable to hold the zipcode
    zipcode varchar;

  BEGIN
    SELECT INTO zipcode substring(provider_nodes.address_postal_code for 5) FROM provider_nodes
      WHERE provider_nodes.npi = npi_id;
    RETURN QUERY SELECT zcta FROM zctas WHERE ST_DWithin(
    geom,
    (
        SELECT geom
        FROM zctas
        WHERE zcta = zipcode
    ),
    7 * 1.6 * 1000
);
   END;
'LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Answer (score 0):

Boils down to this simplified query:

```sql
SELECT d."NPI"
FROM   provider_nodes p
JOIN   zctas z0 ON  z0.zcta = left(p.address_postal_code, 5)
JOIN   zctas z  ON  ST_DWithin(z.geom, z0.geom, 7 * 1.6 * 1000)
JOIN   doc   d  ON "Provider Business Mailing Address Postal Code" = z.zcta
WHERE  p.npi = <your npi_id here>;
```

Your function has multiple shortcomings. If you want to keep it additionally, I suggest:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION get_npizips (npi_id text)
  RETURNS SETOF text
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT z.zcta
FROM   provider_nodes p
JOIN   zctas z0 ON z0.zcta = left(p.address_postal_code, 5)
JOIN   zctas z  ON ST_DWithin(z.geom, z0.geom, 7 * 1.6 * 1000)
WHERE  p.npi = $1
$func$;
```

Use dollar-quoting for the function body.

Don't quote the language name `plpgsql`.

Use of [`ALIAS` is discouraged](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-ALIAS). Use named parameters instead.

No need for PL/pgSQL. A plain SQL function does the job.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Didn't think of it that way :)

Comment: @user2923767: It's the set-based way of thinking as opposed to the procedural one. Hard to translate, one has to re-think the problem ...

Comment: Select query works fine. But the function gives me this error: syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 8:    WHERE  p.npi = $1;

Comment: @user2923767: There was a misplaced semicolon. Removed now.